# Oracle - Retrieve items contained in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently searching the best way to implement a feature for my software.
I am using `Oracle Stored Procedures` to retrieve a list of materials, and one clause would be to search if a field of my material contains one of the strings of another table.

For example:

I have a table with materials defined like this:

> ID, Name, Components

And a table of components defined like this:

> ID, Component

I would like to retrieve each material where Components is contained in at least one of the components defined in the table Component.

Don't know if I'm very clear, but as I'm pretty new to database languages and Oracle, I do my best :)

Thank you very much !

EDIT

Some samples:

Table Component:

```
ID| COMPONENT
_____________
1 | 'TOTO 42'
2 | 'TEST'
3 | 'TEST42'
4 | 'COMP1'
5 | 'CONTROL 25'
```

Table Material:

```
ID| NAME   | COMPONENTS
__________________________
1 | 'MAT1' | 'TOTO 42;TEST'
2 | 'MAT2' | 'CPTX'
3 | 'MAT3' | 'AZER;TYUO'
4 | 'MAT4' | 'PL;MLX;23'
5 | 'MAT5' | 'CONTROL 25;COMP1;MLX'
```

I would like a query on table Material that returns only MAT1 and MAT5 (because one of their components is in the table Component).

Thank you !

Comment: It would help if you provided an example data for those two tables and desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the design isnt very good. You would like to store componets in something like  this

```
    ID,  component
     1,     A
     1,     B
     1,     C
```

So your querys can use index

Lets assume you components is something like `A;B;C`

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/798a0/5)

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.ID, m.NAME
FROM MATERIALS m
JOIN COMPONENT  c 
  ON  ';' || UPPER(m.COMPONENTS) || ';' LIKE '%;' || UPPER(c.Component) || ';%'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | NAME |
|----|------|
|  5 | MAT5 |
|  1 | MAT1 |
```

Comment: I'm using customer's database, and I can't modify it, I only have read access

Comment: Include the test fiddle